# Envio de email em uma api jax-rs json

Tags: java, api, email, restful, jax-rs

Estou com uma demanda para desenvolver uma api que dentre outras funcionalidades precisa enviar emails de aviso, na arquitetura ficou definido que iremos usar javaEE jax-rs alguém já trabalhou com alguma api que integre envio e recebimento de email no java?

Answer (score 0):

API para envio de e-mail em java:

javamail - http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/index.html

commons-email- https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-email/

Comment: Obrigado amigo, consegui resolver!